# Show form from another form

Tags: c++, winforms

I  have 2 forms Form1 and Form2.
How can I, inside code (Form1.h) show Form2 (something like Form2::Show())

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit your .cpp file and arrange the #include directives, putting the 2nd form first:

```
#include "stdafx.h"
#include "Form2.h"
#include "Form1.h"
```

Then write code like this in, say, a button's Click event handler:

```
    System::Void button1_Click(System::Object^  sender, System::EventArgs^  e) {
        Form2^ frm = gcnew Form2;
        frm->Show(this);
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a new instance of the `Form2` class and call its `Show()` method.